# Creating middleware throwing error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

really new to laravel. Im using laravel 5.2. im trying to create a new middleware using "php artisan make:middleware MiddlewareName" but it gives me the following error :

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of
>   Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dms\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServ
>   iceProvider.php on line 62 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dms\vendor\laravel\fra
>   mework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 103

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you also getting error in `php artisan routr:list` ?

Comment: Yeah same error

Comment: You may be have error by any routing. Can you share routings ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually when you have routes outside the 'web' middleware. Kindly check your routes if you have any that is outside.

Comment: im using 5.2 there is only one routes file.